# Restrict certain hosted sites from sending mail on Ubuntu LAMP server

Tags: ubuntu, php, email

I host several live sites, and several staging sites on one server that's running Ubuntu 14.04. Most of the sites are wordpress sites, and are using the php mail() function or the PHPMailer class to send their mail.

What I'd like to do is to prevent certain sites being staged from sending email. Maybe even whitelist the few live domains so that they are the only ones allowed to generate emails.

Is there a quick way to lock down the domains allowed to send mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in the `php.ini` of the Vhost which you want to restrict:

```
disable_functions = mail,exec,shell_exec,passthru,system,proc_open,popen
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the hosted domains connecting to a remote or local MTA?

If it's local, it can be configured for whitelisting by allowing relay just to specific hosts (which you should already be using to prevent you mail server from becoming a spam source).

If remote, just add a default iptables outgoing rule that bans access to remote port 25 and insert the allowed sources before this denying rule.